# Merge a column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables and I want to map one table to another with an id column. These two tables don't have equal size of ids. If the ids are not found, then the column result with n/a.

Table A

```
id   type
2231  C
1213  A
1241  C
```

Table B

```
id     other columns
2232       X
1213       Y
1233       I
```

The goal is to map id values from Table A and add an addition column in Table B.

Ideal Table

```
id     other columns    type
2232       X             n/a
1213       Y             A
1233       I             n/a
```

I tired to find all the Type A from Table A.

```
typeA = df_A.id.loc[df_A.type == 'A']).tolist()
df_B.type = df_B.loc[df_B.isin(typeA)]
    ...
```

I thought about merging the two tables by ids, but they have different id size and maybe there are different ids too. 
Is there a more efficient way to do this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use map

```
dfB['type'] = dfB.id.map(dfA.set_index('id').type)

    id   other columns  type
0   2232    X           NaN
1   1213    Y           A
2   1233    I           NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `id` using parameter `how='left'` and `fillna` with `n/a` as:

```
df_B.merge(df_A,on='id',how='left').fillna('n/a')

     id other columns type
0  2232             X  n/a
1  1213             Y    A
2  1233             I  n/a
```